# cpp_redis::client::multi doesn't work correctly

Tags: c++, redis

What I want to do is create and increase by one in transaction an integer value. In Redis it would be:

```
MULTI
INCR my_counter
EXEC
```

But I need to do it in C++. I've installed and builded cpp_redis library from here https://github.com/Cylix/cpp_redis. Then tried from this fork: https://github.com/cpp-redis/cpp_redis. The build and linking to project in VS2022 was done correctly, following the guide: https://github.com/Cylix/cpp_redis/wiki/Windows-Install.  But regardless which repo I used, I get the same problem: and integer value can't be incremented inside `MULTI`.

I run Redis as Docker container. I connect to local server on my PC. I can increment value without MULTI command in C++ program, BUT I need to do it inside MULTI.

So, here's my code:

```
#include <cpp_redis/cpp_redis>
#include <tacopie/tacopie>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Winsock2.h>
#endif /* _WIN32 */


int main() {

#ifdef _WIN32
    //! Windows netword DLL init
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA data;

    if (WSAStartup(version, &data) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup() failure" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
#endif /* _WIN32 */

    cpp_redis::active_logger = std::unique_ptr<cpp_redis::logger>(new cpp_redis::logger);
    cpp_redis::client client;
    
    // Connect to the Redis server
    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 6379, [&](const std::string& host, std::size_t port, cpp_redis::client::connect_state status) {
        if (status == cpp_redis::client::connect_state::ok) {
            std::cout << "Connected to Redis server: " << host << ":" << port << std::endl;
            
            // Start a transaction
            client.multi([&](cpp_redis::reply& reply) {
                if (reply.is_error()) {
                    std::cerr << "Error starting transaction: " << reply.as_string() << std::endl;
                    return;
                }

                // Create a key and increment it by one
                client.incr("my_counter", [&](cpp_redis::reply& reply) {
                    if (reply.is_integer()) {
                        std::cout << "Incremented value: " << reply.as_integer() << std::endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cerr << "Error incrementing value: " << reply.as_string() << std::endl;
                    }
                });
            });
            
            // Commit the transaction
            client.exec([&](cpp_redis::reply& reply) {
                if (reply.is_error()) {
                    std::cerr << "Error committing transaction: " << reply.as_string() << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Transaction committed successfully." << std::endl;
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Failed to connect to Redis server: " << host << ":" << port << std::endl;
        }
    });

    std::cout << "Before sync_commit..." << std::endl;
    // Run the event loop
    client.sync_commit();
    std::cout << "After sync_commit..." << std::endl;

#ifdef _WIN32
    WSACleanup();
#endif /* _WIN32 */

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Failed to connect to Redis server: 127.0.0.1:6379
Connected to Redis server: 127.0.0.1:6379
Before sync_commit...
Transaction committed successfully.
```

Notice there's no `exited with code 0.`
`client.sync_commit()` just can't be processed. Even though we can see `Transaction committed successfully.`, there's no message `Incremented value: ...` in the console. And when I check Redis container inside Docker with command `GET my_counter`, I get `(nil)`.

**Is there something wrong with my code? Or is it just bug of the library?**

Comment: You say "But regardless which repo I used, I get the same problem: and integer value can't be incremented inside MULTI.". But then you also post "Failed to connect to Redis server: 127.0.0.1:6379". Perhaps you should fix your connection issues before you even start worrying about what your code does...

Comment: "Is there something wrong with my code? Or is it just bug of the library?" - Thousands of people use that library, to think it's a library bug rather than a bug in your code is ... just a little arrogant (and probably wrong) - see [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/).

Comment: @JesperJuhl At first it says that it is not connected, but after that it says the opposite: there is a connection, which is true: when I try to `client.incr("my_counter")` **outside** MULTI block, it works, and program sends command to Redis server after `client.sync_commit()`. When I type GET my_counter in Redis console inside Docker, I get the actual incremented value.
The problem is this command can't be processed inside MULTI block in my program...